# Debian Stable libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386 not found (trying to install Steam)

Tags: debian, drivers, package-management, nvidia, steam

I just installed Debian and now I am trying to set up Steam.

I did the first 2 steps in the [64 bit instructions](https://github.com/GhostSquad57/Steam-Installer-for-Wheezy/wiki) and also installed `ia32-libs`.

But when I run the following:

```
apt-get install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
```

It tells me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-nvidia-glx
```

How can I have `apt-get` locate and install `libgl1-nvidia-glx`?

Comment: You need to enable the i386 arch. Did you do that? `dpkg --add-architecture i386`. Then run `apt-get update`. See https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO. I assume you installed Debian stable (wheezy).

Answer (score 3):

First you have to enable multi-arch support:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

After that run `sudo apt-get update`, and then you can install i386 packages.